# How to migrate from redux to react-query?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-query

I started studying react-query, I can't figure it out.
Please help with an example based on my code

There was such an action and a reducer

```
export const addHighlighting = parent_id => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: types.HANDLE_COMMENT_HIGHLIGHTING,
    payload: {
      parent_id,
      is_highlighted: true
    }
  })
}

case types.HANDLE_COMMENT_HIGHLIGHTING:
      const parentIndex = state.comments.findIndex(
        comment => comment.id == action.payload.parent_id
      )
      return update(state, {
        comments: {
          [parentIndex]: {
            is_highlighted: { $set: action.payload.is_highlighted }
          }
        }
      })
```

there was functionality on the page that raised the status and, when hovering the mouse, highlighted the parent's comment.

```
onMouseEnter={() => addHighlighting(comment.parent)}
onMouseLeave={() => removeHighlighting(comment.parent)}
```

**How now to do also on react-query with mutation?**

Answer (score 2):

The job of React Query is to get data from a server and cache that. That's all.

The job of Redux is to keep data for your application in memory and manage that.

If this highlighting info is not saved somewhere on a server, React Query is the wrong tool for that job.